# How should I release a char pointer by passing a const char pointer for free?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I have the code below in a main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mystruct {const char *name; int x;};

char *test_calloc_char_p(const char *char_p) {
  return (char *) calloc(1, (strlen(char_p) + 1) * sizeof(char));
}

int main(void) {
  struct mystruct *ms1;
  ms1 = (struct mystruct *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct mystruct));
  ms1->name = test_calloc_char_p("dlldffdl");
  ms1->x = 3;
  free(&ms1->name);
  free(ms1);
  return 0;
}
```

Which I compile with `gcc main.c -o test` and run with `./test`, and I get:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Abortado
```

I don't understant, why? I should not release `ms1->name`? because when I comment this line I don't get the error, but why shouldn't I release something that I allocated?

Comment: `free(&ms1->name); ` Why are you taking the address of `ms1->name`?

Comment: it should be `free(ms1->name);` because you want to free the memory that `ms1->name` is pointing to.

Comment: Tip: `calloc(1, (strlen(char_p) + 1) * sizeof(char))` doesn't make much sense. That should be  `calloc(strlen(char_p)+1, sizeof(char))` or `malloc((strlen(char_p) + 1) * sizeof(char))`. Except `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so that should be  `calloc(strlen(char_p)+1, 1)` or `malloc(strlen(char_p)+1)`. Also, the cast the return value isn't needed and therefore dangerous. It should be omitted.

Comment: Tip: You might find `strdup` useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
free(&ms1->name);
```

The address of `ms1->name` is part of the allocated memory assigned to `ms1`.  it is *not* the allocation for the `name` member.

You assigned allocated memory to `ms1->name`, so that is what you should pass to `free`:

```
free((char *)ms1->name);
```

Note that the cast is needed because otherwise you would be passing a `const` pointer to a function expecting a non-`const` pointer.  The cast can be removed  by changing the `name` member from `const char *` to `char *`.

Comment: That's right, I had put the "&" because I got the "expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'const char *'" warning, and I read it quickly, and didn't even realize it was a convertion error. Do I need convert by using "const" or also "char"?

Comment: @PerduGames The error you got was because you were trying to pass a `const` pointer where a non-`const` pointer was expected, so a cast is needed.  The best way to fix this would be to change `name` to `char *` since the memory returned is writable.

Comment: So would it be writable even if I use `const` on the `name` member?

Comment: @PerduGames The `const` means you can't write to it via the `name` member but you can through some other `char *` pointer.  Regardless, you should remove the `const` qualifier.

Comment: True, I tested here, I can record through another pointer anyway, I will remove `const`, it would be nice to show this solution in your answer since it is the most correct.

Answer (score 1):

&ms1->name points to the address of first field in your struct, i.e. it points to ms1 itself.
so ms1, and &ms1->name point to the same address

the code should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mystruct {const char *name; int x;};

int main(void) {
  struct mystruct *ms1;
  ms1 = (struct mystruct *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct mystruct));
  ms1->name = strdup("dlldffdl");
  ms1->x = 3;
  free(ms1->name);
  free(ms1);
  return 0;
}
```

also your function test_calloc_char_p duplicates functionality of strdup

Comment: `free((char*)ms1->name)` is needed to avoid a warning since it's a pointer to a const char for some reason.

Comment: True, but note that `strdup` is not part of the ANSI standard. It is an extension of POSIX.